# Matlab: How to prevent Matlab from cutting decimals in array?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, format, decimal, precision

is it possible to get this in an array with 16 decimals after the comma?
Poorly it gets cut in my Workspace as you can see in the link below.
Kind regards!

```
format long;
startYCoordinateNorthEast=([50.93952193697642, 6.99745722361763]);
```

[here you can see the array, cut to 4 decimals but I need 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp9As.png)

Comment: MATLAB does not cut decimals, it **shows** less decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Matlab workspace, you are right that `format long` will show you the long output:

```
>> startYCoordinateNorthEast

startYCoordinateNorthEast =

  50.939521936976419   6.997457223617630
```

In the Workspace Viewer, to see all the decimals, you must click on the tab called "View". From there, under "Number Display Format" choose "Long Fixed Decimal"